# LAPACK 3.8.0 installation [znep.out] Error 139

Tags: lapack, failed-installation, fedora20

I'm trying to install LAPACK 3.8.0 on fedora 20 to be able to use it for MESA code. I faced the below TESTING error:

make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/aunia/bin/lapack-3.8.0/TESTING/EIG'
NEP: Testing Nonsymmetric Eigenvalue Problem routines
./EIG/xeigtstz < nep.in > znep.out 2>&1
/bin/sh: line 1: 16436 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./EIG/xeigtstz < nep.in > znep.out 2>&1
make[1]: *** [znep.out] Error 139
make[1]: Leaving directory`/home/aunia/bin/lapack-3.8.0/TESTING'
make: *** [lapack_testing] Error 2

I tried to update my gcc-fortran package but it didn't solve the problem. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is reference lapack. Is there a reason, why you would want to install the reference?

```
yum install lapack-devel
```

should do it for you. The only reason, you would want to build lapack yourself would be an optimised version for you specific machine/cpu. In which case I would recommend to not chose the reference but OpenBLAS or Atlas.

Comment: I was trying to install the prerequisites to install and use the cod "MESA" (in FORTRAN of course) so I found this link to help me: https://coral.ise.lehigh.edu/jild13/2016/07/27/install-lapack-and-blas-on-linux-based-systems/  I followed the instruction and came to the mentioned errors.

Comment: thanks yum "install lapack-devel" ran without any error!